# Flexible banner as seen in video

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, video.js

Im trying to duplicate the movement and flexible sizing just like seen in the video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPWsGema_6o

Basically its just 2 div blocks and one is a image and another is video using videojs.
Also once my broswer goes down to a certain width, I would like to move the divs vertically like seen in the video.

Html code:

Css code

```
.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image {
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .image {
    flex: 1 1 100px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #vid {
    flex: 1 1 100px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside de media you can just change de direction of the flex container with `flex-direction: column`, you can remove the `flex-wrap`, since it is not needed

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ...
```

You can know more about the flex basics with this playground

https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv